# Excel: Iterate through column array to find duplicate values in different column array and pair arrays

Tags: arrays, excel

The first column corresponds to a single process and the second column are the components that go into the process. I want to have a loop that can examine all the processes and evaluate what other processes have the same individual components. Ultimately, I want a loop to find what processes have 50% or more of their components match 50% or more of another process.

For example, process 1 has 4 components in common with process 2, so they have more than 50% of their components that pair, so I would want a function to identify this process pairing. The same for process 1 and 3.

```
Process Comp.
1       511
1       233
1       712
1       606
1       4223
1       123
1       456
2       511
2       233
2       606
2       4223
2       222
2       309
2       708
3       309
3       412
3       299
3       511
3       712
3       222
3       708
```

I feel like I could use a network library for this in python or maybe run it in matlab with an iterative fucntion, but I need to do it in excel, and I am new to coding in excel so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a data setup like so and it is sorted by Process number as shown in your provided sample data:

[image]

Use this formula in cell F2 and copy down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1)))/COUNTIF(A:A,D2)
```

Then you can use conditional formatting to turn cells in column F that are greater than 50% green for easier readability.

Comment: Question: why not `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,$B$2:$B$22)*($A$2:$A$22=D2))/COUNTIF(A:A,E2)` Which, yes loops more, but does not require the need of sorting?

Comment: Hello @ScottCraner The only reasons were to prevent the looping as well as allow for whole column references for each instance of column ranges, but it does require the data be sorted unfortunately.  If the data can't be sorted, then your formula would be the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If sorting is not an option then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,$B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))*($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))=D2))/COUNTIF(A:A,D2)
```

If sorting is an option then @tigeravata's answer will be quicker as it iterates fewer times by limiting the range to only the processes involved.

[image]